# LinkedList delete : why don't we override the head with previous?

Tags: java, algorithm, pointers, data-structures, linked-list

Reviewing my data structures, for some new job interview requirements. So I have a delete method for the Linked-List.

```
public Link delete(int key) {
    Link current = first;
    Link previous = first; 
    while(current.iData != key) {
        if(current.next == null) 
            return null;
        else {
            previous = current; 
            current = current.next;
        }
    }

    if(current == first)
        first = first.next;
    else
        // just bypass it
        previous.next = current.next;
    return current;
}
```

I think I understand it so far. But I get curious around this line.

```
// just bypass it
previous.next = current.next;
```

Why don't we override the `head` (in this example represented as `first`) with the `previous` ? Or Would be that wrong logic? like

```
// just bypass it
previous.next = current.next;
first=previous;
```

I mean `previous` and `current` are just pointers to iterate the list. And the real data after the deletion is located in the `first` right? Sorry if that would be weird to think in that why. Sometimes my weird intuition just comes out while studying algorithms mainly because I'm sort of weak

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing so will cause your linked list to lose all the nodes that come before the previous. If you had a linked list with the following values:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

and you called `delete(7)`, your head will point to `6`, and you'll have a linked list of `[6, 8]`.

Comment: Actually after I run it , the`first=previous` line doesn't impact the `previous.next = current.next` result. Eventhough it looks logically correct as your answer, I think my answer can only answered by languange architects, coz they are the ones who design the memory model. For now I just focus on the pointers whenever I encounter this on the interview (i.e. that previous.next = current.next is enough already, coz it's already show the main point of deleting a node)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Your code didn't show how `first` was initialized, so I assumed it to be a member variable of some LinkedList class. How is the memory model is related to this question?

Comment: I satissfied with your answer already. That already answered the question well :)